# how to do Solr indexing of HBase table by using Hadoop MapReduce program?

Tags: solr, mapreduce, hbase

I am new to `Map Reduce`, I have done indexing documents in solr by using Map Reducing.

Now i would like to know how to index a `HBase` table in `solr` by using `Hadoop` `Map Reduce` program.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly depends on how data stored, how many tables should be joined to produce one solr document, but process basicaly the same, as you index documents. Use [TableInputFormat](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormat.html) in your mappers.